# Python: why is my method using os.walk does not return all available paths?

Tags: python, path, subdirectory, os.walk

Question as in title and here's the method:

```
 def walkThroughPath(self , sBasePath, blFolders = True, blFiles = True ):
      aPaths = []
      for sRootDir, aSubFolders, aFiles in os.walk( sBasePath ):
           for sFolder in aSubFolders:
                if blFolders == True:
                     aPaths.append( sRootDir )
                for sFileName in aFiles:
                     if blFiles == True:
                          aPaths.append( sRootDir + "/" + sFileName )

      return aPaths
```

The method returns a big amount of subfolders and files but definetly not all that I've found.

What's wrong with my method (or is it a wrong usage of os.walk)?

For those who are interested in the Background:

http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-10962-centralized_wineprefix_as_preparation_for_debpackages.html

Comment: If you are going use Hungarian Notation [do it right](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).  Even better would be to improve names. Plural for collections, verb+noun for boolean, etc.  Also, is your third for-loop indented correctly?

Comment: Hi Steven, you're right. I even did not know about hungarian notation. Its just the way I am used to code in PHP which I simply ported this to python even if I know that python uses other labeks for their types (and also have other of course) :-). Translation: s=string, a=array, bl=boolean. Clear, that this is not obvious for those who are using such standards. Hope code is understandable anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both of your hints brought the final solution that looks like that now:

```
def walkThroughPath(self , sBasePath, blFolders = True, blFiles = True, blFollowSymlinks = True  ):
    aPaths = []
    for sRootDir, aSubFolders, aFiles in os.walk( sBasePath, blFollowSymlinks ):
        for sFolder in aSubFolders:
            if blFolders == True:
                try:
                    aPaths.index( sRootDir )
                    blPathExists = True
                except:
                    blPathExists = False
                    pass

                if blPathExists == False:
                    aPaths.append( sRootDir )
                    self.logDebug("Append: " + sRootDir )
                    self.logDebug("Current content of aPaths: \n" + pprint.pformat(aPaths) )

        for sFileName in aFiles:
            self.logDebug("Current root dir: " + sRootDir )
            if blFiles == True:
                try:
                    aPaths.index( sRootDir + "/" + sFileName )
                    blPathExists = True
                except:
                    blPathExists = False
                    pass

                if  blPathExists == False:
                    aPaths.append( sRootDir + "/" + sFileName )
            if blFolders == True:
                try:
                    aPaths.index( sRootDir )
                    blPathExists = True
                except:
                    blPathExists = False
                    pass

                if blPathExists == False:
                    aPaths.append( sRootDir )
                    self.logDebug("Append: " + sRootDir )
                    self.logDebug("Current content of aPaths: \n" + pprint.pformat(aPaths) )

    self.logDebug("Folders: " + str(blFolders) )    
    self.logDebug("Files  : " + str(blFiles) )  
    self.logDebug("Paths found in " + sBasePath + " : \n" + pprint.pformat(aPaths) )    
    return aPaths
```

First I indented incorrectly as Steven said.

os.walk seems to handle the lists not as I expected them to be. Folders of files not nessessarily appear in folders list. This caused many folders I left out just because those folder pathes have been in the files list. Additionally I only checked files only in this limited folders list.

Next I added the follow symlinks flag optional as unutbu suggested. Maybe in my case they could be needed as well eventually.

Those method above is surely a candidate for improvement, but it's at least working :-)

Best,

André

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possibilities:

- You don't have permission to read a certain directory.
- [By default, os.walk does not follow symbolic links](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk). Use the
  `followlinks=True` keyword to follow symbolic links:

  ```
  os.walk( sBasePath, followlinks=True )
  ```

Having skimmed the link you provided, it looks like `followlinks=True` may be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you already solved the problem. But for further references: If you want to walk through dirs as an `32 bit application` running on a `64 bit Windows` make sure that you check for the redirected directories.

> The %windir%\System32 directory is reserved for 64-bit applications. Most DLL file names were not changed when 64-bit versions of the DLLs were created, so 32-bit versions of the DLLs are stored in a different directory. WOW64 hides this difference by using a file system redirector.

[File System Redirector on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)